# Detect and Avoid Dead MicroService Instances

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

**TLDR**

I have multiple instances of a single microservice. when one is down and the API gateway has not detected this yet, I get Connection refused: no further information: /10.10.20.101:8132 error. which I want to handle at the API gateway level.

**Explanation**

**My config** - Naming Server, Api Gateway, User Microservice, Core Microservice. naming and API gateway are single instances. other are multiple instances. I expect the API gateway to load balance between the available instances as required. and it works fine in normal cases. the naming server and the API gateway have the normal Eureka configs.

```
>> Naming Server
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
#session timeout
server.servlet.session.timeout=60m

>> Api Gateway
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://microserviceuser:passwordhere@${naming.server.address}/eureka/
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true
eureka.instance.hostname=${naming.server.hostName}
```

nothing special here.

**Problem**

When I take an instance down from the core. this is almost instantly detected by the naming server and removed from the list. this is confirmed by the UI of Eureka.

But this is synced late with the API gateway. it takes a few seconds.  and within that time the load balancer will redirect the request to that dead instance. which gives me `Connection refused: no further information: /10.10.20.101:8132`. which I handle from my end and provide an error to the client. but this is not the behavior I want. the microservice is available to handle this but due to the sync failure gateway is getting this error.

I want the gateway to somehow handle the error and send the request to again a live instance. or remove the dead instance from its local cache for the time being, till gets a new list from the naming server.

How do I fix this?

**Tries**

**Sync Time Change -** Till now I tried to decrease the sync time in the gateway. but I do not think this is a proper solution. with any time gap, the instance can go dead and the client will get the error. and just to sync a list occasionally from the naming server we are just making lots of calls to the naming server from Gateway.

**Circuit Breaker -** Also tried to add the circuit breaker. found that this works on the endpoints, not the microservice instance. so this will just stop the request to the endpoint.

**Retry -** I think retry might work, but this is not sending any request for retry as we are not getting any response coded in the error `Connection refused: no further information: /10.10.20.101:8132` . this is a `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information` and it gives me a null response code. below is part of my `RouteLocator`.

```
....
.filters { f ->
    f
        .retry { retryConfig ->
            retryConfig
                .setRetries(4)
                .setBackoff(
                    RetryGatewayFilterFactory.BackoffConfig(
                        Duration.ofMillis(100),
                        Duration.ofSeconds(4),
                        2,
                        false
                    )
                )
        }
....
```

Any suggestions is appreciated.